# how to check user already exist in th database or not

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I have a form i just want to check whether that user in already exist or not and if not then it save in the database else show error message user already exist in know this question i asked many times but i didnt find my solution 
 here is my aspx code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
    string LastName = tbLastName.Text;
    string Email = tbEmail.Text;
    string Pass = tbPass.Text;
    string ConfirmPass = tbConfirmPass.Text;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
       cmd.CommandText = "Insert into UserDetails(@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Pass,@ConfirmPass)values('" + tbFirstName.Text + "','" + tbLastName.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbConfirmPass.Text + "')";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tbFirstName.Text.Trim());
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", tbLastName.Text.Trim());
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text.Trim());
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", tbPass.Text.Trim());
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPass", tbConfirmPass.Text.Trim());
    }
    con.Close();
    tbFirstName.Text = "";
    tbLastName.Text = "";
    tbEmail.Text = "";
    tbPass.Text = "";
    tbConfirmPass.Text = "";
    tbFirstName.Focus();
    }
```

in this on click event of button user can only be created but i want to verify whether it is present in the database or not

Comment: There have to be at least 100 duplicates of this question.

Comment: @Aaron can you send me the link of few quetion like that

Comment: This search has 697 results - they're not all relevant but I'm sure many on this first page are. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+already+exists+sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, It may help you. call this function on your click event.

```
public void CheckUser()
 {

    string strconn = @"Data Source=appserver3;Initial Catalog=Bart;User ID=bart1;Password=bart@12345";
    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    SqlConnection conn = null;

    conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);
    conn.Open();

    DateTime Dt_Time = DateTime.Now;
    string FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName from UserDetails where @FirstName='" + tbFirstName.Text + "'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tbFirstName.Text.Trim());
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('User Already Exist');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        string strquery = string.Format("insert into UserDetails values('{0}')", @FirstName);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, conn);
        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("FirstName:" + FirstName);               
    }
}
```